# Android - ListFragments in the Same Screen

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm new in android development, and i just got into fragments so im so confused about this.

i want to build and app that takes 2 listfragments, the first one is a categories list and i want that when i click on one of those categories the second listfragment show me the sub-categories of that one, i've used and example from here http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/ to try to understand how information flows but i really can't figure it out, and i really don't know how to do that, any hel would be very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial should be fine for what you want to do, with a few tweaks.

Essentially, the flow of information should be from your category fragment, up to the Activity which contains both fragments, which should then update the sub-category fragment as appropriate (i.e. depending on which category was selected). You *could* update the sub-category fragment from the category fragment but as far as I understand, that's bad practise.

So your Activity knows what is going on in the categories fragment, you'd define an interface of the Fragment (e.g. OnCategorySelectedListener), which the Activity would implement. The category fragment, when it's being attached to an Activity should check that that activity implements OnCategorySelectedListener. Then, when an item in your list of categories is selected, the fragment will call up to the activity and basically says "hey, look, a user wants to know more about category X". The activity will then deal with the logic of determining which category was clicked and so which sub-categories to show.

The [Android developer document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) on fragments is pretty useful in this respect and explains everything thoroughly. Might be work having a look through the samples on that website too, in particular the [News Reader sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/newsreader/src/com/example/android/newsreader/NewsReaderActivity.html).

Good luck!

Comment: ok, i've looked the News Reader Example, and the other fragment it shows is like a simple textlayout, but i would like to do it with 2 listviews or listfragments, the issue i got is the communication between them, i can't figure it out how to do it

Comment: you can just use the same patterns, where instead of updating the TextView, you can update a listview instead